# Can someone explain this prompt for a program?

Tags: c, sorting

> You will first create an interface for handling string items.
>   Basically, you will need to do the following:
>
> Create an interface named item.h  Define a type Item represents a char
>   * (i.e., a c-string)  Implement a less function that compares between two strings and return which
>
> one should precede. Then, you will add to the linked list interface
>   the following functions: linkedlistScanInit:  The header of the
>   function will be linkedlistScaninit(pLinkedList list).    The function
>   takes a linkedlist as input, reads from the command line a set of
>   strings, and store them inside the linkedlist. You can call the
>   function linkedlistAddNode to add a node to the end of the linked
>   list. linkedlistShow: The header of the function will be
>   linkedlistShow(pLinkedList list).     The function takes a linkedlist as
>   input, loops through the linkedlist and show what inside it
>
> Finally, you will create a main, your main will be as follow:
>
> }
>
> You will use the code in linkedListSt.h and linkedListSt.c

sorry its messy its from a pdf and I didn't seem to be able to adjust it without messing it up even more.

So am being asked to basically sort strings in selection sort method on a linked list. my question here isn't anything code specific but what does "less function to compare two strings" mean. does it mean it only needs the declaration?. would that return a string pointer or a string pointer pointer?. Also, I am having trouble understanding the meaning of linkedlistScanInit?

am not entirely sure what the question is here. its not asking me to sort the actual list or at least thats my poor understanding of it.

Comment: I suspect you are being asked to sort in lexical order. Where you compare the strings until you find the first character that differs between the two, and then based on the normal ASCII values for the differing characters, return the lesser to sort first (e.g. `"abat"` sorts before `"acat"` because the value of `'b'` is *less than* the value of `'c'`)

Comment: yes I have already a function written out that does that however the program isn't asking me to create any sort of data structure to contain the strings.

Comment: Generally, when you think about your sort function, `mycmp (const char *s1, const char *s2)`, *less* means that `s1` sorts before (is less) than `s2`, (e.g. `s1 < s2`) and `mycmp` returns `-1`, if the strings are *equal* it returns `0`, if `s1 > s2`, return `1` (just as `strcmp()`) does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing they mean a function which compares which of two strings is 'lesser' than the other, alphabetically.

The function declaration could look something like this:

```
int lessThan(char *a, char *b);
```

which returns 1 if a is lesser than b, and otherwise 0. I'll leave the implementation up to you.

Good luck

Comment: thats simple enough. any idea how  linkedlistScanInit function is supposed to be about?.

again poor wording by my teacher or whoever wrote this but are they asking me to sort the list as I insert it using the function above?.

Comment: You should read lines from the command prompt and store them in the linked list.

Comment: I get that part. Apologies if am being tedious here but my typedefed string item that I was asked to create has no back end to it of any sort except for the typedef declaration as I am not being asked to do any of that however. I have not shown the linked list here but it basically contains pointers to Item types which are typedefed char pointers. Am not sure where to go with that.